# Find two set A and B

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, fixed-point-theorems

Let $S$ and $T$ be sets and let $f: S \to T$ and $g : T \to S$ be arbitrary
functions. Prove that there is a subset $A \subset S$ and a subset $B \subset T$
such that $f(A) = B$ and $g(T \setminus B)= S \setminus A$.

My approach :=

We know that $A=S \setminus A^c$ and
$B= T \setminus B^c$

Now
$f(A)=B$ gives $f(S-A^c)=T \setminus B^c$

Next I will approach...?

Comment: Please give some context for this problem.  Where did you find it?  If it's from a textbook, which one and in which section?  At the moment, your attempt would be appropriate for someone who was only recently introduced to the concept of sets/functions, while a proof likely will likely be very involved, so at the moment I don't have any indication from you what type of argument you would understand.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is a Function From $X$ "into"$Y$ Injective?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2223191/is-a-function-from-x-intoy-injective) or this? [Do there exist sets $A\subseteq X$ and $B\subseteq Y$ such that $f(A)=B$ and $g(Y-B)=X-A$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22581) or that? [Given $f:S\to T$ and $g:T\to S$, prove $\exists A\subseteq S, B\subseteq T$ such that $f(A)=B$ and $g(T\setminus B)=S\setminus A$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320965)

Comment: I have taken this question from Steven G. Krantz book. Page no 123 (question no 21) fourth edition.